# How to suppress debug2 messages during SSH session?

Tags: ssh, terminal, sshd

When I am logged into my home Linux machines via SSH, I get the following debug output a few times every minute:

```
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
```

When I am editing files in nano, the debug message is displayed over top of the text. To remove the debug message, I have to close nano, execute `clear`, and then re-open the file. I get this whether I am using Secure Shell (Google Chrome extension), PuTTY, or Terminator (from local machine), though it's far worse on the former two.

Is there some way to suppress these messages? Will executing `sshd -q` do it, or is the debug output level specified during the compilation process?

Comment: Not a way to prevent the messages, but if you use `Ctrl`-`L`, nano should redraw the screen and get rid of the "junk", without needing to exit and reopen the file.

Comment: I edited `/etc/init/ssh.conf` to add the `-q` option to `sshd -D` and restarted ssh. I then confimed that `sshd` is really running with -q option, it is. I'm still getting the messages though, so I suppose that doesn't suppress the debug2 messages. The man page is typically vague: `-q Quiet mode.  Causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sshd` is the daemon. You'd want to use the `-q` flag with the client (`ssh`).

When connecting to your home machines, include the -q flag in the `ssh` command (i.e. `ssh -q user@host`). Alternatively, if that doesn't work, you could try redirecting stderr to /dev/null by connecting to your home machines like `ssh user@host 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks, I completely spaced on that. Adding -q flag to Secure Shell seems to work. Haven't tried it with the other clients, yet, but I don't see why it wouldn't work with them, too.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I was using

```
ssh -vv
```

to see the detailed debug info and that was the reason why the server was showing

> debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0

in the terminal. I quit the SSH session and then connected again without verbose (`-vv`) and the problem disappeared.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 using Git Bash and had an alias where my `ssh` command was calling it with `-vvv`; maybe that has been why I get so many random debug messages about window size changing etc.

Comment: You can check if yours is getting aliased too using `which ssh` to see what it is actually executing when you run `ssh`

Answer (score 3):

SSH supports in session increases/decreases in verbosity! Here's how to decrease the verbosity:

1. At the command prompt, press Enter/Return. This only works just after pressing Enter
2. Type a tilde `~` character. Notice that it doesn't appear in your terminal - this is by design.
3. Type an uppercase `V` (for "less verbose" - a lowercase `v` makes the output more verbose)

You'll now see some output indicating your current debug level. Keep running through steps 1 - 3 until the debug level is decremented to your liking.

Full credit to https://twitter.com/freebsdfrau/status/1012367229139054594 for teaching me this.

Answer (score 2):

Set `LogLevel INFO` in your server `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. It should hide the most of messages. Also search for other occurrences of this option in that file.

Comment: I've changed the `LogLevel` to `ERROR`. I'm not entirely sure why debug2 messages are being output when `LogLevel` is set to `INFO` though, there is a separate level, `DEBUG2`, for that, it seems (assuming I correctly understand the purpose of `DEBUG2`).

Comment: @AWildColin some of the log messages go also to the client at some condition. But yes, generally you are right.